# Animating constant margin transitions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there a way to animate the position of a constant margin element?

Imagine that we have an element called elem1, which has margin-left of 5px.

After 2 seconds, another element (elem2) is pushed from the left of elem1.

How could we have a smooth transition animation for elem1 instead of changing it's position immediately?

[here's the code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pascal-rtqkv?file=/src/styles.css:0-292)

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution would be adding a CSS animation to one or both of the elements.

[Here's your modified code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-pascal-rtqkv-modified-for-stack-overflow-answer-1r9ks)

Depending on your preferences, you could either add an animation only to the first element (this would push it to the side before the second one appears)

```
.elem1 {
  margin-left: 5px;
  animation: old 1.9s ease-out forwards;
}

.elem2 {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

Or you could add an animation both... I'd probably go with linear for them. The time can be freely modified, as it's not waiting for another element. You could actually modify the time of the first animation too, but watch out - if it's longer than 2 seconds, you risk the elements overlapping for a while.

```
.elem2 {
  background-color: teal;
  animation: new 0.5s linear forwards;
}
```

These are the animations I used for this example:

```
@keyframes new {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
  }
  90% {
    left: 7.5px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

@keyframes old {
  from {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps or at least points you in the right direction, enjoy :)